# Verify schematic and board to get it ready for commercial release

Tags: pcb, schematics

Is there a paid service or platform to hire an electronic engineer to verify a schematic and pcb board I created to get it ready for commercial release?

It's the first schematic I ever created. I taught myself how to create schematics just recently and I'm sure I'm lacking some important knowledge.

I know that there are automatic tools to verify schematics. I however rather want real input and suggestions for improvements.

I don't want to post the schematics on some forum on here.

Comment: It would be cheaper to hire someone to design your stuff from scratch than to find someone to take on the responsibility for your design. That being said most pcb manufacturers will do a basic check for manufacturability, they won't catch true design errors but will catch many things that you may not think of.

Comment: Any idea what it would cost? My version is 40x20cm big and 2 layers.

Comment: So far I verified my schematic by comparing it to a ton of other schematics online, reading a ton about each IC I added and copy parts of other schematics.

I prefer to work on my schematics and learn step by step what can be done better-

Comment: @Flocked In that case, you should learn step by step how to verify your own layouts and designs. For me, receiving, reworking, and reordering faulty boards was a *very* valuable part of the learning process, very much worth the cost of the rework and reorders.

Comment: You are underestimating the scope of work, I think. I imagine someone would have to charge you many hundreds of dollars to review your design and layout. Unless you can find someone in a high skill but low pay area of the world (if there is such a thing in this day and age). You may have to just go through everything the hard way. Order, build, debug, fix the design and re-order, etc.

Comment: I'd like to know what does "commercial release" mean to you? Do you want it simply to work without blowing up so you can sell it to hobbyists, working reliably so you can sell it to professionals as a component, or even pass all electromagnetic interference tests and other certifications required from your device, depending on which device it is (commercial, industrial, medical, automotive) etc? Especially, does the device have connection to mains voltage or any radiofrequency communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what sort of review you are looking to get. Perhaps the better approach is to prototype. It will likely cost you less to try ten times than to pay for an expensive consultant. Professional review is useful but there is an appropriate time in a product development cycle and it may not be with your first ever pcb.

True design review requires a team of dedicated, experienced colleagues. A proper design process is critical - in order to have any hope of checking if the schematic is proper, you must  first specify *and write down* in great detail everything that you are trying to achieve.

As a substitute you may look for a  dedicated engineering consultant, it can be very expensive, they take a lot of risk for looking at your design, imagine if something goes wrong and you think they should have found it.

Review for specific factors, like manufacturing, is more common. You may have already experienced it! If you order a pcb and they say "this copper is too close too edge", that is design for manufacturing/manufacturability (**DFM**) review, because their equipment will not reliably produce such features.

DFM review quality varies by pcb producer, and may be specific to their services. For hobby level facilities it is usually an automated tool to ensure that you follow their rules, for commercial fabs there is usually an actual engineer reviewing your stuff. This can be found third party consultant and is a more standard service.

Other types of specific review, including Design for Test (**DFT**) and design for cost (**DFC**) are also sometimes  offered, the theme here is limited scope and specific deliverables from the review .

As an example, a possible requirement of a review with focus on cost and mass production is to identify single source components and propose alternatives so that production dept can better manage price fluctuations and shortages.

Finally, the better your design documentation the better, and often cheaper, is the review!